# Convert spreadsheet with varying col/rowspans to HTML table

Tags: parsing, spreadsheet

Background:
Our client keeps their rates in a xlsx spreadsheet and wants to be able to upload it to their website and automatically populate an HTML table. Some cells in the spreadsheet cover multiple rows and some cover multiple columns, to fill any blank space, for example:

```
 _______________________
|___|___|___|___|___|   |
|   |   |___|___|___|___|
|   |   |___|___|___|___|
|   |   |___|___|_______|
|___|___|___|___|_______|
|___________________|___|
```

(It may not be possible to determine the column or row spans just by figuring out which cells are empty, even if a cell is on top of an empty cell, it isn't safe to assume it'll span itself and the cell below, since the cell to the left of the empty cell may span 2 columns.)

Another complication is that the rates change all the time, and the client can't be trusted to stick to a pre-made spreadsheet template. (I noticed in the spreadsheet I was using as reference, they had set border correctly, but had not merged cells within the same border.)

Has anyone come across this problem and figured out how to solve it?

Thanks!

Jill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I'll answer my own question. The way I discovered how to do this is to use the [PHPSpreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) getMergeCells() function. It's not very efficient or pretty but it works so...

The code below does the following:

1. First, I use getMergeCells() to collect all the merged cells, stored as an array of strings that look like ["A1:F1", "H6:H7"], from the xlsx file
2. For each cell I check whether it is one of the merged cells
3. If it is, I get the closing cell by splitting the merged cell string by the colon character and keeping the second element
4. Then, I determine which coordinate is different between the merged cell string end coordinate from step 3 and the current cell coordinate. If it's the first coordinate, I increase the rowspan. If it's the second, I increase the colspan.
5. I use a for loop that starts on the x or y coordinate of the current cell, and increases until it matches the merged cell string end coordinate, increasing a variable later used when outputting the table cell that will represent that cell from the spreadsheet

This code is written with Blade, which looks pretty much like PHP, minus the curly brackets with extra '@'s thrown around... I think it's a little more read-able. Please note that the "$file" variable is defined in a different file. I don't use PHPSpreadsheet's getHighestColumn() function because this particular spreadsheet has a lot of stuff going on on the right side of it, but that function is available for anyone who needs it.

```
...
  

 @php
      $reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();
      $reader->setReadEmptyCells(false);

      $spreadsheet = $reader->load($file);
      $table = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
      
      $highestRow = $table->getHighestDataRow(); // e.g. 10
      $columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
      $last_col = $columns[sizeof($columns) - 1];

      $highestColumn = sizeof($columns);
      // **Step 1**
      $mergeCells = $table->getMergeCells();


  @endphp

  <table>
    @for ($row = 4; $row <= $highestRow; $row++)
      <tr>
        @foreach ($columns as $index => $letter_coordinate)

          @php $colspan   = 1;
               $rowspan   = 1;
               $cell      = $table->getCell($letter_coordinate . $row);
               $data      = $cell->getValue();
               // check is data is excel function (or a numerical value)
               if (substr($data, 0, 1) == '=' || is_numeric($data)) {
                $data = number_format((float)$cell->getCalculatedValue() * 100, 2, '.', '') . '%';
               }
          @endphp
          {{-- **Step 2**: Check if cell is merged --}}
          @foreach ($mergeCells as $cells)
            @if ($cell->isInRange($cells))
              {{-- **Step 3** --}}
              @php $limit = explode(":", $cells)[1] @endphp
              {{-- **Step 4** --}}
              @if ($limit[0] != $letter_coordinate) {{-- if letter letter_coordinate doesn't match --}}
                {{-- **Step 5** --}}
                @for ($i = $letter_coordinate; $i != $last_col; $i++)
                  @if ($limit == $i . $row )
                    @break
                  @else
                    @php $colspan++ @endphp
                  @endif
                @endfor
              @else
                {{-- Step 5 (alternative)--}}
                {{-- Find row span --}}
                @for ($i = $row; $i <= $highestRow; $i++)
                  @if ($limit == $letter_coordinate . $i)
                    @break
                  @else
                    @php $rowspan++ @endphp
                  @endif
                @endfor
              @endif
            @endif
          @endforeach
          
          {{-- break to new table if all cells are empty --}}
          @if ($colspan == $highestColumn and $cell == "" and $table_row > 5)
              </tr>
            </table>
             <table>

          @else {{-- if row has one or more cells --}}
            @unless ($cell == "")
             
              <td
                colspan="{{ $colspan }}" 
                rowspan="{{ $rowspan }}"
              >{{ $data }}
              </td>
            @endunless
          @endif
        @endforeach
      </tr>
    @endfor
  </table>
```